# Using Air ANE com.distriqt.Share on Android I get the message "No App can perform this action"

Tags: android, air, share, distriqt

Using Air ANE [com.distriqt.Share](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Share) on Android I get the message "No App can perform this action" when using the method

```
Share.service.share("shareText", image.bitmapData, "url", options);
```

It seems, that the bitmapData is causing this, as using the following parameters works fine (pass "null" for bitmapdata )

```
Share.service.share("shareText", null, "url", options);
```

This is not a solution though, as I need to share the image.

The BitmapData is valid BitmapData, I made sure of this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we answered your question on GitHub, but this is most likely caused by incorrectly adding the FileProvider to your manifest additions in your AIR application descriptor:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
            android:resource="@xml/distriqt_share_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

Make sure you've replaced `APPLICATION_PACKAGE` with your AIR application's java package name, generally your application id prefixed by `air.`.